# Is pod files structure the way to go in ember 2.x apps?

Tags: ember-cli, ember.js-2

Is **pod** structure recommended over the traditional way of organizing files in ember projects using version 2.x ?

Answer (score 1):

Ember pods are a way of structuring your project by feature, instead of type. Instead of having a directory structure with several types (controllers, models, templates...), everything is grouped around a feature (comments, posts...).

So its your decision to go that way. As you application grows you'll be able to easily find the route, model and template for each feature without having to look in a directory with a long list of files.